# problem with python print function

Tags: python, printing, python-3.x

I am trying to this function:

```
def sleep(sec):
    for i in range(sec):
        print(".", end=" ");
        time.sleep(1);
```

the problem is that it waits for the for loop to finish then it prints everything.
If I use the normal print with \n in the end everything works as it should. But with the end=" "
it does not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `stdout` is line buffered. You need to [flush](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-python-print) the output manually.

```
import sys

def sleep(sec):
    for i in range(sec):
        print(".", end=" ")
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(1)
```